# How to create a new database in PostgreSQL 10 in Windows from batch file?

Tags: postgresql, windows, postgresql-10, command-line

I am creating a batch file to create a new database in PostgreSQL 10. I used the following code,

```
echo off
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\10\bin"
psql "dbname=myDB host=localhost user=postgres password=postgres port=5432"
pause
```

But I get this error,

> psql: FATAL:  database "myDB" does not exist

I understand this is not the command to create a new database. I also tried the following code,

```
echo off
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\10\bin"
psql "createdb myDB passfile %APPDATA%\postgresql\pgpass.conf"
pause
```

This is based on the information in [this link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-pgpass.html). The "pgpass.conf" file has the follwoing text,

> localhost:5432:myDB:postgres:postgres

But it asks to enter password. I entered the default password "postgres". But this was the output,

> psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "User1"

The objective here is to create new database from the batch file without asking for password. How to achieve this?

Comment: Surely `createdb` is also available on Windows? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-createdb.html

Comment: `createdb` is a command line program, **not** a SQL statement. `psql` is used to run **SQL** statements, not to execute a command line program. You need to decide if you want to run a SQL statement or a command line program to do that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6405127

Comment: I already tried the method mentioned in the links. As mentioned in the question, the objective here is to create new database from the batch file without asking for password. How to achieve this?

Comment: I think your usage of `passfile` is wrong: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNSTRING  Also, you will need `-U postgres` (or `user=postgres`, depending on which form of connection parameters you are using) in your `createdb` command.  I'd suggest taking one step at a time, carefully reading some introductory material and the error messages.  In this case you could notice that User1 is not the username you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a bat file with the following content and execute it:

```
c:\path\to\postgresql\bin\psql.exe -f C:\path\to\db_create.sql  postgresql://user:password@localhost:port/postgres
```

This is what worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Other way to work for me is:

1.- Create one `test.bat` file with this content:

```
@set PGPASSFILE=D:\bash\Test02.conf
@"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin\"createdb  -U postgres PEDIDOS-2052021141847 

# all in one line
```

2.- Create one `test.conf` file with this content:

```
*:*:*:postgres:1234
# host:port:database:user:password
```

3.- Execute `.bat` file